# Ruby on Rails: Saving form check boxes to Boolean in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Rails noob here, how do I get a Rails form to save a boolean checkbox to postgres? I've tried dozens of things I've found online and none of it is working. No matter what I do, the entry in the Postgres DB is "Null". Here is my 
Model(schema):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171227200151) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "note_title"
    t.string "note_text"
    t.boolean "note_scratch", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "note_info"
    t.boolean "note_reminder"
    t.boolean "note_task"
    t.string "note_tags"
    t.date "note_remind_date"
    t.time "note_remind_time"
    t.integer "note_archived"
    t.date "note_archived_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

view:

```
<%= form_with scope: :note, url: notes_path, local: true do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :note_title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :note_title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :note_text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :note_text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :notes_scratch, "Scratch" %>
    <%= f.check_box :notes_scratch %>
    <%= f.label :notes_info, "Info" %>
    <%= f.check_box :notes_info %>
    <%= f.label :notes_reminder, "Reminder" %>
    <%= f.check_box :notes_reminder %>
    <%= f.label :notes_task, "Task" %>
    <%= f.check_box :notes_task %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :note_tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :note_tags %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :note_remind_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_field :note_remind_date %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :note_remind_time %><br>
    <%= f.time_field :note_remind_time %>
  </p>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
# for testing
  # render plain: params[:note].inspect
    @note = Note.new(note_params)

    @note.save
    redirect_to @note
  end

  private
    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:note_title, :note_text, :note_scratch, :note_info, :note_reminder, :note_task, :note_tags, :note_remind_date, :note_remind_time, :note_archived, :note_archived_date)
  end

end
```

If I just render the form results, it will show checked boxes as 1s, but it always comes up Null in the database, even if I set the datatype to Integer (hoping it would store the 1). All of the other fields record just fine. It's only the checkboxes that don't work.

I appreciate any assistance you can lend!

-Brick

Comment: The answer by @jdgray will probably fix the problem, but when you look at the server response, you should see lines indicating there were unpermitted parameters. That should have been your tip-off.

Answer (score 1):

Review your `note_params` (and `schema.rb`):

```
def note_params
  params.require(:note).permit(:note_title, :note_text, :note_scratch, :note_info, :note_reminder, :note_task, :note_tags, :note_remind_date, :note_remind_time, :note_archived, :note_archived_date)
end
```

In your view: `notes_*` needs to be singular as your schema is `note_*`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'm going to go fix that and hang my head in shame :)

Comment: Np, it happens :)